# marketing cloud connect connection error

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, configuration

**Premise:** I'm following [trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/marketing-cloud-connect/finish-mc-connect-configuration) module to connect MC and SF. All the step until "Connect to Marketing Cloud Within Salesforce CRM" are successful.

**Problem:** In "Connect to Marketing Cloud Within Salesforce CRM", as per the trailhead, we have to put 'username and password' at step 4. Instead of getting an option of putting 'username and password', I'm getting
"Error:
Not Authorized" error after step 3.

Not able to identify what I'm missing... No popup blocker is there, previous all steps also showed success... tried with different browsers as well.

**Note:** SF and MC instances are open in different browsers... and only one instance of each is available.

**P.S:** I'm new to MC, so can anyone please guide that how to debug MC related errors (in detail) such as this.

---

**EDIT:** After clearing cache for multiple times now I'm able to get 'username and password' option ... After entering proper creds, MC is getting verified, getting a green tick at MC side, after that it is getting an automatic redirect to SF (expected behaviour) BUT, after redirection, at SF side I'm still getting the same error 'Error: Not Authorized.'
I'm using classic at SF side, as per the trailhead instructions.

Screenshot attached..

[image]

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the error message? Where do you see it?

Comment: added now (with some further details)...

Comment: Root cause is still NOT found but error is NOT coming anymore... The only things which I did (which may help others in future)... cleared cache multiple times for all the browsers I use... Used incognito mode for MC.... so unsure of the cause but it would be nice if above things may help anyone...
Note: I'm the only person using these MC and SF instances.